On the correspondence between infinitesimal and integral description of connections
It is the title of an article by Petko Nikolov Triste Sissa 1981. I cannot access this pdf yet I remember that it was once avaliable on libgen and now I cannot find it. Please help.

Simply trying Google Scholar leads to these two places: https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:14747322 and http://streaming.ictp.it/preprints/P/81/196.pdf.
